# Is it a good practice to collect different numbers of data (randomly picked) per class?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, dataset

I am totally new to data science and neural networks. So I want to make a simple chord recognition neural network using chroma data from audio. I collected some recordings and songs, and then divide their slices/trims by chords given in the dataset. Is it good for each chord class not having same amount of training audio data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to collect your training data such that it comes from the same distribution as the unseen data. Note that this is not a hard constraint (i.e. your method may still be successful) but can be crucial when using some ML algorithms (like Bayesian approaches which account for prior probabilities).